# javascript: capturing function (f1-12) keys

Tags: javascript, regex, capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling key-press events (F1-F12) using JavaScript and jQuery, cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424407/handling-key-press-events-f1-f12-using-javascript-and-jquery-cross-browser)

I am working to replace an old vb6 app with a web app.  in the old app the save button was linked to f8 and the users of this application want that to stay the same.  How can i capture the f8 button so that it is linked to my save button?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

YOu should be able to bind to the 'keyup' event and look at the keyCode.  Here is a list of the keycodes you will need.

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/javascript-char-codes-key-codes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`DOM_VK_F8 = 119`, so you should check to see that the `keypress` event listener's event object's `keyCode` property is equal to 119.

```
addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 119)
        ; // do stuff here
}, false);
```