# Button with accessKey as F1

Tags: xpages

How do I set the accesskey property of a Button control in XPages to be a function key, e.g. <kbd>F1</kbd>?

The property panel for a Button in XPages only allows a single character. I can compute the value, but I'm not expecting a return value of <kbd>F1</kbd> to work. Is it possible to set the accesskey to one of the function keys or are those keys restricted as browser shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access Key doesn't work for those keys (I have read it somewhere I don't remember. I'll update when I find).

You may also use Dojo for cross-browser solution.

This is an example how to register keypress events:

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/how-to-listen-for-onkepress-event-td1870699.html

This is the list of keys for Jojo:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/keys.html

Answer (score 2):

This Stack Overflow question (with answers) might be useful for you:
[Handling key-press events (F1-F12) using JavaScript and jQuery, cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424407/handling-key-press-events-f1-f12-using-javascript-and-jquery-cross-browser)