# Is it possible to use function keys (F2, F3...F11) in a web application?

Tags: browser

I'm trying to use the function keys in a web application. 
For example, if the user presses F2 or F3, the app must do something.
Is this possible? 
Thanks

Comment: Check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424407/handling-key-press-events-f1-f12-using-javascript-and-jquery-cross-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a jQuery solution, using [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").keydown(function(key) {
            if (key.which == 113) { // F2 key
                alert("testing");
            }
        });
    });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  Test page. 
 </body>
</html>
```

Note - the function keys might be reserved for other uses (e.g. F5 is 'refresh page'), so using these keys might not be advisable.