# Want to click f12 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on one project in which I disabled **f12** and **right click** using jquery and its working fine.
Code for it:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
 if(event.keyCode==123){
  return false;
 }
 else if(event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode==73){
    return false;  //Prevent from ctrl+shift+i
 }
});

$(document).on("contextmenu",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there any way so that I can click **f12** key using jquery.
I want this because I am facing one issue. 
eg. If google.com is already opened with insect element and then I load my page then it shows me inspect element. So I want to hide inspect window on page load.

Is there any way???

Comment: I feel the need for the obligatory users can easily get around these types of things, so *if* this is being used as some kind of security measure, it will only 1) annoy regular users who expect this website to work like others (highlight+right click+copy text for example), and  2) not hinder anybody trying to do anything nefarious.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to simulate a keypress onload?

Comment: I agree with Tom, why would you ever want to do this? It won't stop people using the developer console if that is your intention...

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible because f12 is attached with browser and not with page. JavaScript can only make communication with page.

Source: **[Handling key-press events (F1-F12) using JavaScript and jQuery, cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424407/handling-key-press-events-f1-f12-using-javascript-and-jquery-cross-browser)**

Answer (score 0):

Simply: You can't.

The Dev Tools are not **sandboxed** (unlike any web page), thus granting **sandboxed** environments the power to open and control an **unsandboxed** environment is a major security design flaw.

I hope this answers your question :-)