# Detecting ctrl+f6 from javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, keypress, onkeypress

I am working on an application where I need to detect whether user has pressed **ctrl+f6** for certain navigation path. How to capture <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> key press event in javascript/jquery?

Comment: Possibly the answer lies in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424407/handling-key-press-events-f1-f12-using-javascript-and-jquery-cross-browser

Comment: Right. Missed it somehow. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps ([source](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes))

```js
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 117 ) { //f6 keycode
    console.log("Hey! Ctrl + F6 event captured!");
    event.preventDefault(); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Hit Ctrl + F6 to see console log on this event.
```