# Prevent default on select focused

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

I am trying to prevent default on press F1 so it doesn't open a new tab to support.google.com, instead I want to use it as a hotkey for my app, this is working everywhere, except when I focus a select element for some reason. I put an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <input type="text">

    <select onkeydown="" name="" id="">
        <option value="a">a</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    })
    document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    })
    document.getElementsByTagName('option')[0].addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    })
</script>
```

Here if you press F1, it wont do anything, if you focus on the input and press F1 won't do anythin also, but if you open the select dropdown and press F1 then is going to open the help tab. Thats the problem. Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT: So it seems to be a windows/chrome bug, in mozilla this same code works as expected. The prevent event in select and option are not necesary but I put them just in case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to attach the event handler on the document rather than `window` or a particular element:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "F1") {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("F1 Pressed!");
  };
}, false);
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="a">a</option>
</select>
```

Also your code overrides the `onkeydown` on the `<select>` tag. Kindly remove that too.

In the above preview, irrespective of your focus is on the `<select>` tag or not, <kbd>F1</kbd> is being controlled by JavaScript.

Preview here:

[image: preview]

Comment: Have you tested this on windows? For me it's not working yet, Im having the same result, I'v opened your example in a new tab and it opens help tab still.

Comment: So in mozilla is working fine, is just chrome

Comment: @Of3lia I am using a MacOS.

Comment: So it seems like it is a windows/chrome bug then... With your solution is not changing too much than with mine using window object instead of document , dont know  the exact difference, but tested my solution on mozilla, and also works fine, so it seems to me like a bug related to chrome.

Comment: @Of3lia Yes, also in Windows, you can't reliably use F keys as they don't even come in JavaScript side if you're using Edge / Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Of3lia Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/436489 Very important info might help you out too.